# How to pop up calender and date pick up into the text box in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I pop up calender and selected date(dd/mm/yyyy) pick up into the text box in ASP.NET using C# ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax calendar extender..

1. Add AJAX toolkit reference in your project.

   ```
   <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1"   CssClass="cmnText cmncalendar" runat="server" Width="95px"  ></asp:TextBox>

   <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy"
              Enabled="True" TargetControlID="textbox1">
          </asp:CalendarExtender>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [Calendar link](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) it has everything you want. You need to use [ajax control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx).

Comment: Is it possible to add AJAX Control Toolkit into Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 ??

Comment: @ARIT: Check out this link. Though I have never used Ajax toolkit on VS 2005. This is what you can do. http://forums.asp.net/t/1338884.aspx?ajax+control+toolkit+for+VS2005       Another useful link here: http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.sg/2009/02/installing-ajax-control-toolkit-for.html

Comment: @ARIT:  Here is Ajax toolkit office page which talks about using the toolkit with .net framework 2.0 :  http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/